# setInterval's interval always changes to 1 second (1000ms) after a few iterations

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am just trying to create a simple counter using setInterval. However, after 5 seconds, the interval slows down to about 1000ms. I'm sure I am just overlooking something silly, but for the life of me I cant see it.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var num = document.getElementById('num');
btn.addEventListener("click", startCounter);

var interval;

function startCounter(){
  interval = setInterval(count, 100);
}

var idx = 0;

function count(){
  idx++;
  console.log(idx);
  num.textContent = idx;
  if(idx > 100) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    idx = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<div id="num" style="">0</div>
```

Comment: It's working as expected for me in Chrome.

Comment: you also leak your timer handle

Comment: It's working fine as expected, I don't see any lag or issues in this code.

Comment: I guess that you change your active tab. The minimal interval time in an inactive tab is one second https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? :D

Comment: Oh weird. It works in FF and Chrome, but not in Edge.

Comment: Even after installing the latest Edge update, it doesn't work. Very bizarre. I guess I'll switch to another browser.

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons why an interval might be longer than expected. They are outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). `setInterval` follows the same rules as `setTimeout`.